# How to destroy cloned elements if dropped in a droppable on first drop?

Tags: jquery-ui

Spelling app.  I have a bunch of letter tiles, user clicks a tile and drags it (a clone) down to spell a word.  But they can currently drop them ONTO the tiles they're supposed to be choosing from (div "#tiles").  I have it set up so that if they drag them BACK there, they disappear, but I can't figure out how to destroy them on that initial drag.

putting  $(ui.helper).remove(); and  ui.remove(); together in my droppable : drop solves it, makes the cloned tile disappear.  But it also destroys the functionality of the original tile (it's still visible but no longer draggable).

```
  $(function() {
    $('.tiles').draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        snap: true,
        scroll: false,
        containment: 'window',
        snapTolerance: 30,
        start: function(e, ui) {
            ui.helper.addClass("clones");
        }
    });
    $('.tiles').bind('dragstop', function(event, ui) {
        $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable({
            snap: true,
            snapTolerance: 30,
            scroll: false,
            containment: 'window',
            classes: {
                "ui-draggable": "clones"
            }
        }));
    });

    $('#optionbar').droppable({
        accept: ".tiles",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).remove();
        }
    });


    $('#tiles').droppable({
        accept: ".tiles, .clones",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            console.info("inside2");
            $(ui.helper).remove();
         //   ui.remove(); //this makes it vanish (yay) but also kills it (oops)
        }
    }); 
  });
```

On first drag the cloned tile isn't removed.  If I pick up the same tile and drag it again, it is.  I want them to be destroyed on FIRST drag if they are dropped inside #tiles, but I need my original unmoved tile to remain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to disable droppable upon drop after appending the item.

Comment: You may also consider sortable for the drop zone instead. This way User can add letters and re-arrange them.

Comment: Thank you, Twisty!  I am not sure exactly what you mean.  Am I allowed to post a URL so you can see what I mean?  I have TONS of tiles I'm trying to drop all into the same space.  Here is the URL, I hope I"m allowed to post it: http://phonics.homeschoolertools.com

Comment: I am very new to jquery and not really sure what I'm doing at all!  Appreciate the help!

Comment: Ok, I see what you're working on. So you do not have specific spots they can drop letters to, they snap into spots. And what you want is referred to as collision detection, where an item cannot be dragged onto another item and dropped, but collides with it's edge. I'll see if I can work up an example for you, but it'll take a bit of time.

Comment: Well, my thought was to make it so that tiles dropped onto the #tiles div would vanish.  And they do, but not on "first" drop, for some reason.  If you pick them up (same clone) and drop it again, it does vanish.   But not the first time.  I can't figure out how to map the clone before it's dropped.  If I remove() the original draggable, obviously the original vanishes, but if I remove() the helper, it only removes on the second (or beyond) drop.

Comment: To be clear, when a user takes a tile from the top, you want it to appear there until they drop it. The dropped item should be appended and the original should go away. Is that the case?

Comment: Sorry, no I don't want the original to go away.  I want the user to be able to use the tiles to spell, say, "bee", using the e twice.  Basically it does work exactly the way I want, EXCEPT currently you can drop tiles onto the "bank" of tiles -- I don't want them to  be able to be dropped there, only in the empty space below.  I don't want the tiles on top to ever disappear or be covered up.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So there are two methods that can be used. 1) While dragging, prevent the item from being able to be dragged over an existing tile (collision detection). 2) in Drop, if it detects an item "under" it, shift the letter in a specific direction (Left or Right I suspect). The first option may be the better of the two. Will work up an example for that.

Comment: That sounds awesome, thank you!! :D

Comment: An example to look at: https://medium.com/@edgarleonardo/draggable-and-collisions-with-jquery-13cb7e4903f6 still working on it to fit better with your code.

Comment: Work in progress: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fpzsa50n/122/